# What is the minimum value of Corr(X,Y)+Corr(X,Z)+Corr(Y,Z)

Tags: probability, correlation

Assume X, Y, Z are three random variables, what is the minimum value of corr(X,Y)+corr(X,Z)+corr(Y,Z),
here corr(X, Y) means the correlation between X and Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the correlations are defined, we may assume the variances are all finite and nonzero.  Moreover, correlations are unchanged under scaling and adding a constant, we may assume the variances are all $1$ and the means are all $0$.  So we want to minimize
$\mathbb E[XY + YZ + XZ]$ subject to $\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[Y] = \mathbb E[Z] = 0$
and $\mathbb E[X^2] = \mathbb E[Y^2] = \mathbb E[Z^2] = 1$.

Now note that $\mathbb E[XY + YZ + XZ] = \mathbb E[(X+Y+Z)^2 - X^2 - Y^2 - Z^2]/2$.
But $(X+Y+Z)^2 \ge 0$, so a lower bound is $-3/2$, and this is attained when there are
three outcomes, one with $X = 2/\sqrt{6}, Y=-1/\sqrt{6}, Z=-1/\sqrt{6}$, one with $X=-1/\sqrt{6}, Y=2/\sqrt{6},Z=-1/\sqrt{6}$, and one with $X=-1/\sqrt{6},Y=-1/\sqrt{6},Z=2/\sqrt{6}$, each with probability $1/3$.

Comment: A question: it seems to me that since the question has a "symmetry" between $X, Y$ and $Z$, in the sense that you can exchange any two of them and not change the problem, I would expect the answer to reflect this. Yet, in your answer, the exchange between $Z$ and any of the $X, Y$ is lost. May I ask what is your intuition on this?

Comment: It's not lost.  My answer is symmetric under permutations of $X,Y,Z$.

Comment: Oh, you mean that under any permutation, the symmetry is obtained by a permutation of the possible solutions?

Comment: Permutations of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ permute the three outcomes.  Since they have equal probabilities, the probability distribution stays the same.